# Get a variable in the rails initializers in in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

i need to access a variable in config/initializers/myFile.rb, in my models, i am having a ActiveSupport subscribe method in this file

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "deliver.action_mailer" do |name, started, finished, unique_id, data|

::EstablishmentRoutingHashes = the_hash_route

end
```

I want to access this variable in my model

```
class Establishment < ActiveRecord::Base
    EstablishmentRoutingHashes // want to use it in here
end
```

But i get this error **NameError in EstablishmentsController#create
uninitialized constant Establishment::EstablishmentRoutingHashes**

I did this with another instrumentation and it worked, whats different is that this one comes from a custom instrumentation event that i have in one of my controllers

```
def create
 ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("create.application", @payload_hash)
end
```

Can you guys give me a direction on how to solve this error.

Comment: Is `Establishment::RoutingHash` or `EstablishmentRoutingHashes` a typo? This are two different Constantes. The uniitialized constant is `RoutingHash`  within class `Establishment`. But you use constant `EstablishmentRoutingHashes`

Comment: I just changed the constant name, just to make it a bit descriptive

Comment: I have edited my question to include the actual error, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

`::EstablishmentRoutingHashes` is a constant. You should assign a value only once to a constant. `deliver.action_mailer` is triggered multiple times so you will see multiple warnings like `warning: already initialized constant ...`. But this is not the cause for your error.

Your error `NameError in EstablishmentsController#create uninitialized constant Establishment::EstablishmentRoutingHashes` is displayed because this constant is not defined when your Rails-App starts. It will be defined the first time your code for the `subscribe` block is executed.

When you use async delivery methods like sidekiq or some thing simalar it will get even worse because this block is called within the job and not the Rails-App.

Even for multithreaded servers like puma you run into race conditions.

I think you need a different approach to solve your intital issue.

You have to do some thing like:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "deliver.action_mailer" do |name, started, finished, unique_id, data|

   new_establishment = Establishment.find_or_create ...
   establishment.execute_an_action the_hash_route

end
```

Comment: Im trying use EstablishmentRoutingHashes constant to hold some that from the

Comment: I am trying to use the EstablishmentRoutingHashes constant to hold some data from the "deliver.action_mailer" event instrument payload and send it to my model, i want to do this for every "deliver.action_mailer" event that will occur in the application, what you are saying regarding the constant is actually true, i dont understand the other explanation and the code at the bottom

Comment: Basically you have a concurrency issue. You can't use a global state (like a global variable) to transfer informations to you'r record / model. Wihtin a threaded environment a global state can be changed from multiple threats at the same time and you will not get the expected result. A work a round can be `Thread.current`. But it does not work when you use an external ActiveJob like sidekiq. Because in this case it's not only another threat it's an external process. Best you handle all things within the `subscribe` block.